# Apache HTTP Proxy Based on Hostname

Tags: apache, tomcat, configuration, webserver

Previously, I had Apache HTTP set up correctly to forward incoming HTTP requests on port 80 to my Tomcat instance running on port 8080. However, now I am in such a situation where I need to be able to proxy incoming requests on port 80 to either Tomcat @ 8080 or a different process @ 9000, depending on hostname. Below is a snippet of my attempt at setting up my Apache configuration to handle such a case:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName hostname1
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://hostname1:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://hostname1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName hostname2
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://hostname2:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://hostname2:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when requesting from either **hostname1** or **hostname2**, I get an instant 500 apparently due to  mod_proxy not finding any matching rules to proxy the request:

```
[Fri Feb 08 06:41:01 2013] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

**Note that Tomcat is not receiving the incoming requests, and thus no log output**

For sanity's sake, I checked that I indeed *can access these two resources individually at their respective ports*, i.e. I can access **hostname1** using hostname1:8080 and **hostname2** using hostname2:9000.

Are there things missing here to help me configure this correctly?

Additionally, are there any better ways of managing this in perhaps a more sane manner?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: is your "hostname" fully qualified? Also, what are you seeing in your log files? Is there anything getting into your tomcat logs?

Comment: Fully qualified as in "name.com" (sans "www"), yes.

Comment: Added Apache error logs above

Comment: have you tried to remove them one at a time to make sure they are working independently of each other?

Comment: Removing the latter VirtualHost had no effect. The only way it was working before was by using no VirtualHost's, and only using mod_proxy as `ProxyPass / http://hostname1:8080/ ...... ProxyPassReverse / http://hostname1:8080/`

Comment: Maybe try using NameVirtualHost instead of VirtualHost?

Comment: Or make sure you are using ServerAlias within your VirtualHost directives http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer seemed to be a faulty configuration regarding a separate module, namely mod_proxy_http. I came to the following serverfault answer helped me, as tipped off by the "proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL" message in the Apache HTTP error logs: https://serverfault.com/questions/242650/setting-up-a-basic-mod-proxy-virtual-host

Comment: Too bad the link doesn't go to the answer, which is just `sudo a2enmod proxy_http` - in any case, THANKS!

Comment: @jerluc: HTML isn't a protocol, did you mean `mod_proxy_http`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to configure name-based virtual hosts, add the `NameVirtualHost` directive.

Add `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot` to each `VirtualHost`.

Example:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName hostname1
 DocumentRoot /www/hostname1
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyPass / http://hostname1:8080/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://hostname1:8080/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName hostname2
  DocumentRoot /www/hostname2
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://hostname2:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://hostname2:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: NameVirtualHost is already set to such value, pardon the omission. ServerName is also clearly being used in the configuration I provided. Additionally, I see absolutely no reason why DocumentRoot would make sense at all, considering both hosts are being set up as being proxied.

Answer (score 1):

If you have in error log:

> If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy
>   submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.

Do this command:

```
a2enmod proxy_http
```